# Tailwind with React and Ruby on Rails

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, tailwind-css

I have a new Rails app with a React frontend, and I want to use Tailwind in my React frontend, but my styles are not applying. I installed tailwind with just `yarn add tailwindcss`  and then ran `npx tailwindcss init`

Here is the current file structure displaying the relevant files for my project:

```
my-proj
├── Gemfile
├── Gemfile.lock
├── Procfile.dev
├── README.md
├── Rakefile
├── app
│   ├── assets
│   ├── channels
│   ├── controllers
│   ├── helpers
│   ├── javascript
│   │   ├── controllers
│   │   ├── entrypoints
│   │   │   ├── App.tsx
│   │   │   └── index.tsx
│   │   ├── features
│   │   │   └── HomeView.tsx
│   │   ├── pages
│   │   │   ├── Home.tsx
│   │   └── routes
│   ├── jobs
│   ├── mailers
│   ├── models
│   └── views
│       ├── home
│       │   └── index.html.erb
│       ├── layouts
│       │   ├── application.html.erb
│       │   ├── mailer.html.erb
│       │   └── mailer.text.erb
├── bin
├── config
├── config.ru
├── db
├── lib
├── log
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── public
├── storage
├── tailwind.config.js
├── tailwind.css
├── test
├── tmp
├── tsconfig.json
├── vendor
└── yarn.lock
```

And this is what my tailwind.config.js file looks like:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./app/javascript/entrypoints/*.tsx",
    "./app/javascript/features/*.tsx",
    "./app/javascript/pages/*.tsx",
    "./app/views/home/*.html.erb"
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

As you can see, I have my tailwind.config.js file and my tailwind.css file with the directives in the root of the project, and I've referred to all the files that would contain any tailwind styling (I only included the html.erb files since the application.html.erb file is the entrypoint). I started off simply with these basic styles just to test it out, but I'm not seeing anything:

```
import React from 'react'

const HomeView = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p className="text-blue-500 text-lg">This is the homepage component</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default HomeView
```

I understand that there are different setups for React and Rails, but I only plan on using this in my React files, as that will make up all the frontend, and based on the documentation, this is all that's required. I've seen some mention of needing another build command in the package.json file and I added a simple one:

```
"build:tailwind": "tailwind build tailwind.css"
```

But that isn't working either. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: `"text-blue text-large"` - these are not tailwind classes. https://tailwindcss.com/docs/text-color https://tailwindcss.com/docs/font-size

Comment: @Alex I apologize, those were typos I made in the confusion of trying to get this to work. I've edited my question to reflect what I'm trying to do, as I'm still having the same issue.

Comment: why aren't you using https://github.com/rails/cssbundling-rails

Comment: I was unaware that I would need that, as I thought my setup should resemble a basic React setup with Tailwind, since I will be using Tailwind in the React side of my app. I will try this. Thank you